# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS too slow after suspend and resume on dell

Tags: 18.04, suspend, dell

I have a dell vostro 5470, i7-4510U, 8gb ram, GeForce GT 740M 2gb and recently added ssd 240gb(it only has the ssd now) and i have just installed  ubuntu 18.04 LTS.
As you can see in this video: https://youtu.be/vy1rQhRalJ0
It takes a very long time to resume. I tried at least 10 approaches to solve this issue without sucess. 
I have nvidia driver(nvidia-390) installed
I edited the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` variables in `etc/default/grub`
I installed msr-tools and ran sudo wrmsr -a 0x19a 0x0
I checked this in dell website: https://www.dell.com/community/Inspiron/Suspend-resume-problems-on-Ubuntu-18-04/td-p/6072410

And so on...

I hope the video can help you understand what kind of problem it is. I really tried a lot before coming here. I hope someone could help, thanks

Comment: I could not identify the cause of the problem, but it was solved by reinstalling ubuntu OS.